# Flutter call popup form widget that's in another file

Tags: flutter

I have 10 different forms for the user to add different objects to a db. I want them in separate `.dart` files to manage them easier.

I want the forms to be a popup dialog so I need `showDialog()`.

I managed to get the popup form to work when user presses `onPress()` in `main.dart` but cannot work out how to create a separate form widget file that pops up when `onPress()` is selected from `main.dart`.

Here's the code:

`main.dart`

```
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(useMaterial3: true, colorScheme: lightColorScheme),
      darkTheme: ThemeData(useMaterial3: true, colorScheme: darkColorScheme),
      home: const Home(),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const int tabsCount = 3;
    return DefaultTabController(
      initialIndex: 0,
      length: tabsCount,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(

// more code

floatingActionButton: SpeedDial(
          backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFE9C46A),
          buttonSize: Size(90, 90),
          tooltip: 'Add any Object',
          overlayColor: Colors.grey,
          overlayOpacity: 0.8,
          icon: Icons.add,
          //animatedIcon: AnimatedIcons.add,
          curve: Curves.linear,
          children: [
            SpeedDialChild(
              child: Icon(Icons.person),
              label: "Person",
              backgroundColor: Color.blue,
              onTap: () {           //I want to put part this in a widget in another file 
                showDialog(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return AlertDialog(
                      scrollable: true,
                      title: const Text("Login"),
                      content: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Form(
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              TextFormField(
                                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                  labelText: "Name",
                                  icon: Icon(Icons.account_box),
                                ),
                              ),
                              TextFormField(
                                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                  labelText: "Email",
                                  icon: Icon(Icons.email),
                                ),
                              ),
                              TextFormField(
                                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                  labelText: "Message",
                                  icon: Icon(Icons.message),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      actions: [
                        ElevatedButton(
                          child: const Text("submit"),
                          onPressed: () {
                            // your code
                          },
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
                  },
                );
              },
            ),
            SpeedDialChild(child:
// more code to the eof
}
```

Change above to this:
`onTap: () { CustomForm() }`

and in `Custom_Form_Widget.dart` I tried the below and many other variations:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomForm extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomForm({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return AlertDialog(

//rest of the code
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        **1. you could create this way in the custom_form_widget.dart**
        
        class CustomForm extends StatefulWidget {
      const CustomForm({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      _CustomFormState createState() => _CustomFormState();
    }
    
    class _CustomFormState extends State<CustomForm> {
      final TextEditingController _nameController = TextEditingController();
      final TextEditingController _emailController = TextEditingController();
      final TextEditingController _messageController = TextEditingController();
    
      @override
      void dispose() {
        _nameController.dispose();
        _emailController.dispose();
        _messageController.dispose();
        super.dispose();
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          scrollable: true,
          title: const Text("Login"),
          content: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Form(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  TextFormField(
                    controller: _nameController,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      labelText: "Name",
                      icon: Icon(Icons.account_box),
                    ),
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    controller: _emailController,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      labelText: "Email",
                      icon: Icon(Icons.email),
                    ),
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    controller: _messageController,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      labelText: "Message",
                      icon: Icon(Icons.message),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          actions: [
            ElevatedButton(
              child: const Text("submit"),
              onPressed: () {
                String name = _nameController.text;
                String email = _emailController.text;
                String message = _messageController.text;
                // do something with the input data
                Navigator.pop(context); // close the dialog
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      }
    }

  **2. how to call the form.**

 Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          // more code
        ),
        floatingActionButton: SpeedDial(
          backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFE9C46A),
          buttonSize: Size(90, 90),
          tooltip: 'Add any Object',
          overlayColor: Colors.grey,
          overlayOpacity: 0.8,
          icon: Icons.add,
          curve: Curves.linear,
          children: [
            SpeedDialChild(
              child: Icon(Icons.person),
              label: "Person",
              backgroundColor: Color.blue,
              onTap: () {
                showDialog(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return CustomForm();
                  },
                );
              },
            ),
            // more code to the eof
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was after. Thank you so much. So `showDialog()` stays in `main.dart`. I thought once you called the form widget that would execute the popup from `showDialog()` in that widget. But you call the popup from `main.dart` and the form (or whatever you're calling) is wrapped in it.